# Use a key sequence to escape from command-line mode in vimperator

Tags: vimperator

Is it possible to use a key sequence (I like to use ,.) to escape from command-line mode in vimperator? I have remaped ,. to  like this:

```
" leader key
map , <Leader>

map <leader>. <Esc>
```

I never got this working in vim, but in evil-mode (emacs), when I'm in command-line mode, I can return to normal mode by using ,. This works really well and I'd like the same behaviour in vimperator. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following mapping

```
cnoremap ,. <Esc>
```